# HTML tag replacement regex not quite working correctly

Tags: html, vb.net, regex, xhtml, tidy

This is a follow up to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212758/build-regex-to-find-and-replace-invalid-html-attributes) of mine.  The solution I found worked great for every one of the test cases I threw at it, until a case showed up that eluded me the first time around.

My goal is to reformat improperly formatted tag attributes using regex (I know, probably not a fool-proof method as I'm finding out, but bear with me).

My functions:

```
Public Function ConvertMarkupAttributeQuoteType(ByVal html As String) As String
    Dim findTags As String = "</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^'"">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>"
    Return Regex.Replace(html, findTags, AddressOf EvaluateTag)
End Function

Private Function EvaluateTag(ByVal match As Match) As String
    Dim attributes As String = "\s*=\s*(?:(['""])(?<g1>(?:(?!\1).)*)\1|(?<g1>\S+))"
    Return Regex.Replace(match.Value, attributes, "='$2'")
End Function
```

The regex in the `EvaluateTag` function will correctly transform HTML like

```
<table border=2 cellpadding='2' cellspacing="1">
```

into

```
<table border='2' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='1'>
```

You'll notice I'm forcing attribute values to be surrounded by single quotes -- don't worry about that. The case that it breaks on is if the *last* attribute value doesn't have anything around it.

```
<table width=100 border=0>
```

comes out of the regex replace as

```
<table width='100' border='0>'
```

with the last single quote incorrectly outside of the tag.  I've confessed before that I'm not good at regex at all; I just haven't taken the time to understand everything it can do.  So, I'm asking for some help adjusting the `EvaluateTag` regex so that it can handle this final case.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll be a lot better off using an HTML cleaning tool (as da8 suggested on your other question) or parsing the HTML with a forgiving DOM and re-exporting it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

richardtallent's explanation of why the regex wasn't working pointed me in the right direction.  After playing around a bit, the following replacement for the EvaluateTag function seems to be working.

Can anybody see anything problematic with it?  The change I made is in the last group after the pipe.  Maybe it could even more simplified further?

```
 Private Function EvaluateTag(ByVal match As Match) As String
   Dim attributes As String = "\s*=\s*(?:(['""])(?<g1>(?:(?!\1).)*)\1|(?<g1>[^>\s]+))"
   Return Regex.Replace(match.Value, attributes, "='$2'")
 End Function
```

If no one responds I'll probably accept this as the answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The first RegEx function will pass EvaluateTag the *entire* match, which is the entire HTML tag.

But EvaluateTag doesn't ignore the final greater-than character...

I'm afraid I haven't had enough caffeine yet to work through the entire expression, but this adjustment *may* work (added a greater-than in the character list):

```
 Private Function EvaluateTag(ByVal match As Match) As String
   Dim attributes As String = "\s*=\s*(?:(['"">])(?<g1>(?:(?!\1).)*)\1|(?<g1>\S+))"
   Return Regex.Replace(match.Value, attributes, "='$2'")
 End Function
```

Comment: That didn't quite work.  Actually, it didn't have any effect at all on the original regex.